# onclick not picked up by custom element

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, native-web-component

I'm defining a custom element

```
customElements.define("my-button", class extends HTMLButtonElement {
  onclick() {
    console.log("bar");
  }
}, { extends: "button" })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tuxkjp3q/

But when I click it nothing happens.

Why is that and how can I attach event handlers to each instance of the class without overriding the constructor?

#### Edit:

When I inspect the DOM object there is an onclick handler, but it's not functioning. This is confusing

[image]

#### Edit 2:

Further findings, when omitted from the prototype, defining a handler works

```
customElements.define("my-button", class extends HTMLButtonElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onclick = () => console.log("bar");
  }
}, { extends: "button" })
```

But when the prototype contains `onclick`, the same handler no longer functions

```
customElements.define("my-button", class extends HTMLButtonElement {
  onclick() {
    console.log("bar");
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onclick = () => console.log("bar");
  }
}, { extends: "button" })
```

I would be really happy if we can get an explanation of this phenomenon.

#### EDIT 3:

I've come up with a work around, if anyone faces the same problem. It's probably worth noting that only handlers defined in the direct prototype of the instantiated class will get attached, which is good for performance but probably flawed logic. Anyhow it could be tuned to your requirements.

```
// Only in the base class
constructor() {
  super();

  for (let prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.constructor.prototype)) {
    if (prop.indexOf("on") === 0) {
      this.addEventListener(prop.substring(2).toLowerCase(), this.constructor.prototype[prop]);
    }
  }
}
```

I am still very interested in learning the reason for this.

Comment: Why don't you want to override the constructor?

Comment: @Supersharp it's a design decision, or in simple words - it's ugly. There is one additional issue, say I use `addEventListener` but my listeners are actually bound to the prototype of the class and are using `on*` names, then one day the standard changes and implements the expected in this question behavior, then you would have the same handler called twice which will most likely result in broken applications.

Comment: FYI: Customized Built-Ins (extending anything but HTMLElement) will never work in Safari; Apple refuses to implement this part of the standard. Note edit #3 still allows for ``this.onclick`` definitions. The reason it doesn't work as you expect (today) is because inline handlers go 25 years back. ``this.onclick`` is ancient (totally valid and most of (my) time preferred) method; different **NOTATION** from ``addEventListener`` handlers (preferred method according to textbooks written after 2010) When ES6 ``class`` was introduced they (I guess) didn't want to make it work with (old) notation.

Comment: Note 2: #3 is going to get you in memory troubles.. you are adding Listeners everywhere, but not removing them. Garbage Collect might catch most/some, but generally if you add a Listener you are also responsible for removing that listener (in the ``disconnectedCallback``)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman sounds to me like safari will be the new ie if apple don't pull their shit together. Could you provide any sources for note 2? I believe listeners get collected along with the element.

Comment: The usual GC blogs. By your question I can tell you know what you are doing. Myself, I wouldn't do your.. rather blunt.. edit #3 though, you are attaching a shitload of listeners, besides click there is also ``ondragstart`` and many of his companions...JavaScript is a weird beast sometimes, don't fight it.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman you probably have missed something, I'm currently using a slightly modified version of this approach and my elements only have a few listeners attached - as many as I have defined in the class itself. Perhaps you missed that it will only attach a listener if the class has its own property starting with "on". This is not very useful once you start extending a class and you wonder why it's parent's `on*`s are not working, so in my modified version I allowed for that with a simple tweak but I didn't add it here because it's a little harder to understand and requires a call.

Comment: See the code I appended to your question. You are fighting the *JavaScript Beast* with **hundreds** of unnecessary ``ON`` listeners... Well, it is not *fighting*, you are so busy with listeners you already lost...

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Yes that is exactly what I meant, those properties will not get picked up because my example will be running on a class that extends `HTMLElement` which will not have them as *own* properties. Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xfLneu3r/). Obviously this should be used as a mixin or something.

Comment: It is your code, it is your party. ``this.onclick = this.onClick;`` achieves the same. Well .. almost the same, strictly speaking it is another handler (it is "old" JavaScript, not an Event Listener added by ``addEventListener``). But the purpose is a button click gets processed. With Components I prefer this notation, as a user can easily overwrite it... which can't be done with a Listener added with ``addEventListener`` unless the Component provider has included a ``removeListener`` method.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman yes it does, that's in essence this question. Why does it work if I assign it in the constructor but not if in the prototype. I just chose the better solution for the workaround.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you need to define the listener of click... not the function onClick

```
class CustomButton extends HTMLButtonElement  {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('clicked');
    });
  }
}

customElements.define('custom-button', CustomButton, { extends: "button" });
```

html

```
<button is="custom-button">
  Hi
</button>
```

Comment: I specifically pointed out that I'm looking for a solution without overriding the constructor. By defining the function `onclick` I should be defining what is essentially the `onclick` event attribute. Which works fine if I declare it in `my-button` as an HTML tag, not via JavaScript though.

Answer (score 1):

For an `EventTarget`, it is the setter of the [`onXYZ` event handler IDL attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-idl-attributes) that adds the listener to the `XYZ` event. [IDL attributes are analogous to JavaScript properties.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IDL#content_versus_idl_attributes)

[Method definitions](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#sec-runtime-semantics-methoddefinitionevaluation) (and [public class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields)) invoke the `[[DefineOwnProperty]]` internal method, not the `[[Set]]` internal method. (See `DefinePropertyOrThrow` in the ecma262 standard link.) Thus these do not add the event listener.

On the other hand, the assignment `this.onclick = () => console.log("bar")` inside the constructor [does actually invoke the `[[Set]]` internal method](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) (See `PutValue` in the link). Therefore it does add the event listener.

When you **both** define a `onXYZ` property in the prototype **and** set `this.onXYZ`, the setter `EventTarget.prototype.onXYZ` is overridden by `this.prototype.onXYZ`, and the event handler is not added.

Answer (score 0):

All you've really done is create an `onclick` property for your custom element and assigned a function to it. Just because it's named `onclick` does not inherently mean that the system knows it's a `click` event because you are making your own element. [You will need to create a custom event for your custom element.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent)

Comment: Thank you for your time! As seen in edit 2, if it's added as a property then the system knows it's an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Your are very blunt in attaching all handlers that start with **on**

Guess how many there could be:

```js
document.body.append(
  ...Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).filter(prop => prop.indexOf("on") === 0)
  .map((prop, idx, arr) => {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = `${arr.length-idx} &nbsp; ${prop}`;
    return div;
  }));
```

You don't have to use `addEventListener`;

Using the (*old*) `this.onclick=` handler in Components ***can*** be more flexible,
because the user of the Component can easily overwrite it.
With `addEventListener` the **author** of the Component has to provide an `removeListener` method; otherwise the user can not remove a listener.

Information on the different JavaScript Event Models:

- https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html

Comment: As discussed in the comments, this is improper use of my example. Try running it on `window.constructor.prototype` and see how many there are.