# Why the event handler of CustomEvent of my web component doesn't called if it was subscribed via html attribute?

Tags: javascript, web-component

Windows 10 x64, Google Chrome v87.0.4280.66.

If I subscribe to my component's event via JavaScript then my event handler works fine. But if I try to do the same via attributes in the HTML-file then my event handler doesn't work.

So, it works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Custom component</title>
</head>
<body>
<custom-counter id="counter" counter="5"></custom-counter>
<script src="custom-counter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

code:

```
// custom-counter.js

class CustomCounter extends HTMLElement {

    static get htmlTagName() { return "custom-counter"; }

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    #shadow;

    #render() {
        console.log("#render called");
        if(this.#shadow) {
            this.#shadow.getElementById("counter").textContent = `* ${this.counter.toString()} *`;
        }
    }

    get counter() {
        const attName = "counter";
        return this.hasAttribute(attName) ? parseInt(this.getAttribute(attName)) : 0;
    }

    set counter(value) {
        const attName = "counter";
        this.setAttribute(attName, value);
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("counterchanged", {detail: { value: this.counter}}));
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.#shadow = this.attachShadow({mode:"closed"});
        this.#shadow.innerHTML = `<div><span id="counter">* ${this.counter} *</span></div>`;
        const element = this.#shadow.getElementById("counter");
        element.style.background = "yellow";
        element.addEventListener("click", event => ++this.counter);
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(attName, oldValue, newValue) {
        console.log(`The '${attName}' attribute changed. oldValue: ${oldValue}. newValue: ${newValue}`);
        this.#render();
    }

    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ["counter", "counterchanged"];
    }
}

customElements.whenDefined(CustomCounter.htmlTagName).then(
    () => console.log(`'${CustomCounter.htmlTagName}' web component is defined.`));

if(!customElements.get(CustomCounter.htmlTagName)) {
    customElements.define(CustomCounter.htmlTagName, CustomCounter);
}

// It works fine:
const counter = document.getElementById("counter");
counter.addEventListener("counterchanged", event => console.log(event.detail));
```

It seems like this:

[image]

Console output (when I click on my web component):

[image]

Ok. Now I want to move the event registration from code to html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Custom component</title>
</head>
<body>
<custom-counter id="counter" counter="5" oncounterchanged="console.log(event.detail)"></custom-counter>
<script src="custom-counter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

code:

```
// custom-counter.js

class CustomCounter extends HTMLElement {

    static get htmlTagName() { return "custom-counter"; }

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    #shadow;

    #render() {
        console.log("#render called");
        if(this.#shadow) {
            this.#shadow.getElementById("counter").textContent = `* ${this.counter.toString()} *`;
        }
    }

    get counter() {
        const attName = "counter";
        return this.hasAttribute(attName) ? parseInt(this.getAttribute(attName)) : 0;
    }

    set counter(value) {
        const attName = "counter";
        this.setAttribute(attName, value);
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("counterchanged", {detail: { value: this.counter}}));
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.#shadow = this.attachShadow({mode:"closed"});
        this.#shadow.innerHTML = `<div><span id="counter">* ${this.counter} *</span></div>`;
        const element = this.#shadow.getElementById("counter");
        element.style.background = "yellow";
        element.addEventListener("click", event => ++this.counter);
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(attName, oldValue, newValue) {
        console.log(`The '${attName}' attribute changed. oldValue: ${oldValue}. newValue: ${newValue}`);
        this.#render();
    }

    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ["counter", "counterchanged"];
    }
}

customElements.whenDefined(CustomCounter.htmlTagName).then(
    () => console.log(`'${CustomCounter.htmlTagName}' web component is defined.`));

if(!customElements.get(CustomCounter.htmlTagName)) {
    customElements.define(CustomCounter.htmlTagName, CustomCounter);
}

// It works fine:
/* const counter = document.getElementById("counter");
counter.addEventListener("counterchanged", event => console.log(event.detail));
*/
```

But now my event handler doesn't work:

[image]

Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself (look the comment in the `connectedCallback` function):

```
// custom-counter.js

class CustomCounter extends HTMLElement {

    static get htmlTagName() { return "custom-counter"; }

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    #shadow;

    #render() {
        console.log("#render called");
        if(this.#shadow) {
            this.#shadow.getElementById("counter").textContent = `* ${this.counter.toString()} *`;
        }
    }

    get counter() {
        const attName = "counter";
        return this.hasAttribute(attName) ? parseInt(this.getAttribute(attName)) : 0;
    }

    set counter(value) {
        const attName = "counter";
        this.setAttribute(attName, value);
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("counterchanged", {detail: { value: this.counter}}));
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.#shadow = this.attachShadow({mode:"closed"});
        this.#shadow.innerHTML = `<div><span id="counter">* ${this.counter} *</span></div>`;
        const element = this.#shadow.getElementById("counter");
        element.style.background = "yellow";
        element.addEventListener("click", event => ++this.counter);
        
        // I added this code block:
        if(this.hasAttribute("oncounterchanged")) {
            const code = this.getAttribute("oncounterchanged");
            if(code){
                this.addEventListener("counterchanged", new Function(code));
            }
        }
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(attName, oldValue, newValue) {
        console.log(`The '${attName}' attribute changed. oldValue: ${oldValue}. newValue: ${newValue}`);
        this.#render();
    }

    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ["counter"];
    }
}

customElements.whenDefined(CustomCounter.htmlTagName).then(
    () => console.log(`'${CustomCounter.htmlTagName}' web component is defined.`));

if(!customElements.get(CustomCounter.htmlTagName)) {
    customElements.define(CustomCounter.htmlTagName, CustomCounter);
}

// It works fine:
/* const counter = document.getElementById("counter");
counter.addEventListener("counterchanged", event => console.log(event.detail));
*/
```

Comment: You can't create an **inline** ``on...`` event handler yourself, you can only use the default inline event handlers. Also note ``this.#shadow`` is not required, ``attachShadow()`` both sets **and** returns ``this.shadowRoot`` Also note your Custom Event won't escape shadowDOM unless you specify the ``composed:true`` option.

Comment: But I did inline `on...` event and it works. Look my code above. I need to have `this.#shadow` because I created the shadow DOM in the `closed` mode. I emmit the event not in the shadow DOM but I do it on my web component directly (without `composed:true`), therefore I can subscribe outside of the component. It works.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that ``closed``; never seen a WC in the wild that uses it. I also missed where exactly you dispatch the Event from; I see now you have a closed component that communicates to **itself**, why don't you put that listener callback code in the counter Setter? You have a ``oncounterchanged`` Attribute on your element, it is not an Event*handler* like ``onclick`` would create, your code works because you check for a string and then add a modern Event*Listener* yourself.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, it was an artificial example, written on the knees to show the problem.

Comment: Cool; so your root cause is: ``oncounterchanged`` is never an Event Handler, only an Attribute on the element. Note, there is a dirty trick to make it work... use any of the many existing, but unused in your code, **on...** handlers on an element, and trigger that Event. There 107 on-handlers on the window Object (Elements less): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64190442/onclick-not-picked-up-by-custom-element/64843365#

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, Thanks. I was just trying to figure out how I can add a custom event to the web component so that I could specify a handler for it in the html page. I may have invented the bicycle. Then I ask you to suggest how this is done correctly.